# Can we check the uniqueness of latitude and longitude while using gecoder gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder, validates-uniqueness-of

Using geocoder gem in my web services ,   the server side we need to validate the uniqueness of location added.Is this possible with the geocoder gem, we don't want the same location twice in our database.

Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a uniqueness validation on the model:

```
validates :latitude, uniqueness: {scope: :longitude}
```

Comment: Thanks @infused.In between does this validate the location ? I mean a pair of latitude and longitude?